# continue if service not starts

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

I am installing windows service (actually few of them), and this is the snippet of one of them:

```
<Component Id="cmpD9168A36C32F8D411B6EF4270EE6544F" Guid="{E5811AB8-0949-4C75-99BD-6687EB4672D4}" Win64="yes">
          <File Id="filD9168A36C32F8D411B6EF4270EE6544F" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.LoggerService.ProjectDir)\bin\LoggerService.exe" />
          <ServiceInstall
              Id="loggerServiceInstaller"
              Type="ownProcess"
              Vital="yes"
              Name="$(var.Manufacturer)LoggerService"
              DisplayName="$(var.Manufacturer)LoggerService"
              Start="auto"
              Account="[PROP_DOMAINUSER]"
              Password="[PROP_PASSWORD]"
              ErrorControl="ignore"
              Interactive="no">
            <ServiceDependency Id="LanmanWorkstation"/>
            <ServiceDependency Id="LanmanServer"/>
          </ServiceInstall>
          <ServiceControl Id="loggerStartService" Start="install"  Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)LoggerService" Wait="yes" />
        </Component>
```

Now, during the installation service will attempt to start but by design it might fail, and it's ok. But now, when service fails, it asks if i want to cancel or retry. How can I just ignore the failure?

Comment: Have you tried setting ServiceControl@Wait to No?

Answer (score 4):

Usually this is a problem with the design of the service.  For example I've answered questions on StackOverflow where developers say that their service calls a web service during startup and it takes longer then the 30 seconds MSI allows for start up.   My answer is always "really??".

That's poor design.  The OnStart() of a service should be doing nothing more then spinning up a background worker thread and reporting success.  That thread should then be initializing and processing work.   The pipeline for OnStart needs to have minimal dependency and minimal execution time.

Comment: Alas, few services follow that advice. Even some of the ones that ship with Windows by default don't.

Comment: Sadly, agreed.  At a former company, I fought a developer, tooth and nail, who wanted a registry value changed to configure the SCM to wait longer for a service to start.  I argued that this was an inappropriate change to the customers machine and forced them to refactor their code.  A couple years later I was installing a Microsoft product (TFS I think)... anyone want to guess what that installer informed me that it needed to do?